# Python: mock import statement of another file

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I am in the situation where I have a class that imports two libraries that have the same interface, and in the `__init__()` decides which one to use depending on some conditions:

```py
# class_file.py

import lib1
import lib22

class A:
    def __init__(self, condition):
        if condition:    
            self.attr = lib1
        else:
            self.attr = lib2
```

Since both `lib1` and `lib2` cannot be used in testing, I need to mock them. But I do not want to fully replace the `__init__()`, I just want that when `A.__init__()` will be called, the lines `self.attr = lib1` or `self.attr = lib2` will use a mocked version of `lib1` and `lib2`:

```py
# test.py
from class_file import A

def get_mocked_a():
    # How to substitute lib1 and lib2 in class_file.py so that the following
    # line will return an object where self.attr is mocked?
    return A()

def test():
    a = get_mocked_a()
```

How can I achieve this? I need `get_mocked_a()` to be a function, because `A` is pretty complex to instantiate, therefore it's much cleaner to obtain an instance of `A` in test functions by calling it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to mock some functionality direct in your test cases then try this.

```
from unittest import mock
                
#inside your test
def test():
  with mock.patch('your_function_of_choosen_library', return_value='what_you_want_to_return'):
     #your code
```

Edited:

```
from class_file import A
    
def get_mocked_a():    
   with mock.patch('your_function_of_choosen_library', return_value='A'):
      return A
    
def test():
  a = get_mocked_a()
```

Comment: this does not answer the question at all nor is it properly formated

Comment: what does making test cases have to do with answering a question? you haven’t answered the question that OP has posed properly, not to mention the code you posted isn’t even valid Python due to indentation errors.